# MiniProfiler v4 dependency on .net standard

Tags: c#, .net, mvc-mini-profiler

Trying to install MiniProfiler v4 (4.0.0) and get an error related to the following:

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that 
are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

However on nuget, it only really mentions .net framework:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/4.0.0

Comment: This issue is reported. Check here https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/317.

Comment: Thanks, reported it but seems like they have no interest in fixing it. seems like a major issue for such a common tool.